# ImportError when importing file from another directory

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I am playing around with the AIMA python project, but I'm having trouble with importing the `logic.py` file into `main.py`. The following is folder structure:

```
project/
    aima/
        __init__.py
        utils.py
        logic.py
    main.py
```

I added the folder to my python path variable. Every time I do

```
# main.py
import aima.logic as logic
```

I get this error:

> File "main.py", line 2, in 
>       import aima.logic as logic
>     File "/project/aima/logic.py", line 34, in 
>       from utils import (
>   ImportError: No module named 'utils'

I thought this was strange since `logic.py` imports the utils file it should be fine since they are under the same directory.

I tried searching for answers, but most of them mention adding to python module search path and adding `__init__.py` and do not work for me.

Comment: I suspect that python is confusing utils from some other default python path.  Can you try renaming your utils.py to aimautils or something like that and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Use `from aima import logic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying this may be good

```
  from project.aima import logic
```

Comment: Yup, it worked. But I had to add the `aima` folder to the python search path instead of the `project` folder.